# Program to read input lines of any length in C

Tags: c, input, output

And I want it to print to output as is. Curently I am using this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 2000
int main(void)
{
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  while(fgets (buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin) !=NULL)
    {
     printf("%s",buffer);
}
 return 0;
}
```

Then I want the program to be able to skip html tags in the original text but I don't know exactly how to work around that.

Comment: Yep, I have been able to figure out how to read and print from output and how to get rid of whitespace and tabs but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get rid of html tags

Comment: This question will surely not help you in that endeavor since it is for something else.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (at least on Posix compliant systems). Your `fgets`  based code won't work with very long lines (because a very long line would be "truncated": all of it would be read, but only `BUFFER_SIZE` characters would have been copied, and the rest of the line ignored).

You could code

```
 char* linebuf=NULL;
 size_t linesize=0;
 while (!feof(stdin)) {
     ssize_t linelen = getline(&linebuf, &linesize, stdin);
     if (linelen<0) { perror("getline"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
     fputs(linebuf, stdout);
 }
```

In the above code, the `linebuf` will (unless failure) be grown to the widest line size. You should `free(linebuf)` after that loop...

Comment: Why *not* use `fgets`? Its behavior on longer-than-asked strings is [documented](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/): if the allocated size is enough to end with a return, it'll do so. Else you get a NULL character at the end, and no return. Pro: it will work with *any* line length. Con: you need a bit of bookkeeping for those "longer than assumed" strings (see the OP's target).